# sans serif (sub(sub(section)) title appearance

Tags: sans-serif

I want that all `\section`, `\subsection` & `\subsubsection` entries that appear in the resulting pdf file are displayed with a sans serif font. I already tried to redefine the `\section` command as follows: `\renewcommand{\section{}}{\section{\textsf{}}}`. Unfortionately, this doesn't format. The reason probably is that I don't pass the argument of `\section`. How can I define the redefinition correctly? Francky @Leyn.eu

Comment: file:///usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ko‌​ma-script/scrguien.p‌​df

Comment: file:///usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ko‌​ma-script/scrguien.p‌​df : how can one access this file?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I was not careful! Try [this link](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf).